# Мне нужно симулировать нажатие на клавиши

Tags: python, linux, клавиатура

У меня есть vps, на который возможно установить лишь дистрибутив Linux.
Так же, у меня есть скрипт на Python, который должен писать текст, симулируя клавиши. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы он вводил некоторые данные в окно.
Но, к сожалению, он либо ничего не пишет, либо пишет лишь ASCII.
Я испробовал Debian 9, Debian 10, Ubuntu 18.04, нигде это не работает.
Пробовал через подключаться через `VNC` и `RDP`, пробовал `Gnome`, `XFCE`, `LXDE`, все равно скрипт не работает.
Для ввода я использую `pynput` приблизительно таким образом:

```
import pynput
x = pynput.Keyboard.Controller()
text = 'русский_текст'
for i in text:
    x.press(i)
```

К сожалению, оно категорически отказывается писать русские буквы.
Писал `setxkbmap -layout us,ru -variant ',winkeys' -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll'`.
И  `DISPLAY=:id python3 -c 'import pynput'` вводить я пробовал.
Перезапускал ОС.
Пробовал заменить на другой пакет, но они тоже адекватно не работают. Хотел сделать через `keyboard`, но когда я пытаюсь симулировать нажатие, допустим 3 клавиш, оно пишет лишь одну букву на русском при текущей английской раскладке(???).
Пробовал `pyuserinput`, тоже не работает.
Потратил последние 7 часов, невероятно устав, но ничего не вышло.
Простите если недостаточно описал всю суть проблемы - просто подскажите как писать русские и английские буквы на UNIX системе.
Если возможно посылать нажатия прямо в процесс - это тоже подойдёт.
На Windows всё работает идеально.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.
Локали я пробовал менять и на `UTF-8`, и на `CP-1251`. Текущая система: `Ubuntu 18.04`, подключаюсь через `VNC`, а окружение - `XFCE`.
Текущие локали(все равно не работает):

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.ISO-8859-5"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.ISO-8859-5
```

Comment: как мне видится, ваша проблема не в области python, а в области локалей серверных дистрибутивов linux. Добавил соответствующую метку к вопросу.

Comment: Кодировка OC и программы на python совпадают? Попробуйте приложить вывод команды `locale` с сервера в вопрос

Comment: @PotroNik, добавил текущие локали.
Я могу писать на русской раскладке, интерфейс тоже русский. Но ```pynput```, к сожалению, не работает.

Comment: такая же проблема! Правда на windows

Comment: Можно попробовать другим инструментом для проверки, например: `xdotool search --name "Untitled" windowactivate --sync type "русский_текст"`. Будет работать? `xdotool` надо установить из репозитория. Вместо `"Untitled"` имя нужного окна. Я создал новый документ в **LibreOffice**, по умолчанию окно называется *"Untitled"*, выполнил вышеуказанную команду и получил набранный *"русский_текст"* в этом окне. OC: **Ubuntu 18.04**.

Comment: Да, всё сработало. Очень вас благодарю, мне стоит переделать через этот инструмент весь скрипт, или он сильно кушает производительность?

Comment: @malatindez Когда отвечаете кому-то нужно указывать '@имя', чтобы адресат получил уведомление. Например, `@Minimax`. Нет, `xdotool` был для проверки, думаю лучше разобраться с `pynput`, если у вас всё остальное на Python. Скорее всего вы что-то неправильно делаете. Обратите внимание, что в случае `xdotool` указывается целевое окно, в которое будут направлены  "нажатия" клавиш. В случае же `pynput` такой опции нет, а окно-получатель указать всё равно надо, иначе как скрипт поймёт куда ему отправлять нажатия клавиш - окон-то много? Как это сделать я пока не понял.

Comment: @MiniMax, я пробовал сделать до этого через ```pyperclip``` и симуляцию нажатия на ```ctrl+v``` - это работало, но не очень хорошо, сейчас сделал через ```cmd = xdotool search --name \"{0}\" windowactivate -- sync type \"{1}\".format(window, text);  os.system(cmd)``` и всё, кажется, работает хорошо. Медленней, чем на Windows, но это хоть что-то.

Answer (score 2):

попробуй библиотеку [pyautoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/), Она позволяет симулировать нажатия на клавиши `pyautogui.press('esc') # Simulate pressing the Escape key.`
либо просто писать текст сразу  `pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.25)  # Type with quarter-second pause in between each key.`
Только ее начала надо установить `pip install PyAutoGUI`и импортировать `import pyautogui`